# ngx-translate: use with interfaces, *ngFor and switch

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I'd been assigned the duty of translating a sidebar in Angular using ngx-translate. The element to be translated is an interface that will represent the type of user granted

```
export interface userType {
 role: [string, string];
 operations: [string, string, string][];
}
```

In order to know the user's type, we placed in the componets.ts a switch conditional

```
switch(typeOfUser) {
case 'ROLE_CLIENT':
(() => {
this.userType = {
role: ['EnglishStr', 'EnglishStr'],
operations: ['EnglishStr', 'EnglishStr', 'EnglishStr']
}})}
```

I already translated the strings in the es.json file, but literally, word by word.

```
"EnglishStr": "SpanishStr"
```

Now, in the component.html we do have an *ngFor to iterate through the userType.operations

```
    <li *ngFor="let string of userType.operations">
      <a routerLink="{{ string[2] }}">
        <i class="{{ string[0] }} me-3"></i>
        <span> {{ string[1] | translate}} </span>
      </a>
    </li>
```

And although the translate pipe it does the work I was asked for: is there a better approach to resolve this? 
I tried this way in the es.json

```
userType : {
role: ['SpanishStr', 'SpanishStr'],
operations: ['SpanishStr', 'SpanishStr', 'SpanishStr'] }
```

Which didn't translate from English to Spanish. Why was my first approach incorrect? Is it there a different approach to the one I used? Thanks very much

Comment: `string` is a reserved variable type. Never ever name you variables `string`. I am surprised that your compiler doesn't report an error here.

Comment: What do you mean by `With no result`? What is the output you get an what is the output you expect?

Comment: You are right, but I wasn't in that part of the project. Many hands at deck. And yes, the compiler doesn't give any warnings about that at all.[Lynx242](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6749601/lynx-242)

Comment: When reading the ngx-translate documentation, it explain different ways of placing the data in the json documents. When I used the method described above, ngx-translate didn't translate from English to Spanish. then, when wrote it down word by word, does the desired effect and translate it with no problem. which is means that my first approach wasn't correct [Lynx242](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6749601/lynx-242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I browsed through the ngx-translate docs. I can't find any hint according to the approach you describe here. And I have to add that I used ngx-translate for several years in different projects.

The aim of translators is always to have one single identifier string by which you then go into the JSON-file of the currently activated language and search for the matching translation.

In your example you have

**en.json**

```
{
   "name": "name",
   "age":  "age"
}
```

**es.json**

```
{
   "name": "nombre",
   "age": "edad"
}
```

And then the UI will show either the english or the spanish string-representation of this identifier.

There is no way around.

To make it more obvious you could use more specific identifiers like this, for example

**en.json**

```
{
   "global.name": "name",
   "global.age":  "age",
   "xyz.component.direction": "direction",
   "abc.component.working-hours": "working hours"
}
```

**es.json**

```
   "global.name": "nombre",
   "global.age":  "edad",
   "xyz.component.direction": "dirección",
   "abc.component.working-hours": "horas laborales"
```

Comment: [Lynx242](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6749601/lynx-242) Much appreciated. As it is my first time with ngx-translate, I thought that was my lack of experience/ knowledge not to know how to use ngx-translate in a *ngFor.

Comment: No problem. I wasn't sure what your question's aim might be. Now it's clear. ;)

Comment: PS: If you found my explanation useful I'd appreciate if you would mark it as solution to your question. thx in advance.